# multiple double y-axis plots via loop R

Tags: r

I have the following code to create a simple split y-axis plot.
I would like to loop through (as an example) the edhec data set so that each panel in a matrix of panels has two lines: the first vector of edhec on the left and one of subsequent vectors on the right:

```
library(zoo)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)

data(edhec)
edhec <- as.zoo(edhec)
plot(edhec[ ,1], ylab=colnames(edhec[ ,1]), lwd=2)
par(new=TRUE)
plot(edhec[ ,2], ann=FALSE, yaxt="n", col="darkgreen", lwd=1)
axis(side=4)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What kind of looping have you attempted in an effort to get to what you desire? Additionally, looping may not be the best way to achieve your intended result, however if we can see what you've tried it's easier to glean your intent.

Comment: Get rid of `par(new = TRUE)` and use any of the standard methods for putting base plots together: `par(mfrow)` or `par(mfcol)` or `layout` or `split.screen`... (they all have help pages).

Comment: I use the word 'looping' loosely as my brain is stuck in VBA - but a variation of lapply would be ideal too. The code for creating the matrix of plots is this. I don't really know how to combine the two or whether this is the right way to go about it.

Comment: my.panel <- function(x, ...) {
      lines(x, ...)
      panel.number <- parent.frame()$panel.number
    }
    plot.zoo(edhec, main = "title", plot.type = "multiple", lwd = 1.5, col = 
    "blue", panel = my.panel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing this is roughly what you want?

```
library(zoo)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)

data(edhec)
edhec <- as.zoo(edhec)

par(mfrow=c(ceiling(ncol(edhec)/2), 2), 
  mar=c(0, 2, 0, 2), oma=c(2, 0, 1, 0), mgp=c(2, 0.7, 0))

invisible(lapply(1:ncol(edhec), 
  function(x) {
      par(new=FALSE)
      plot(edhec[, x], 
        xaxt=ifelse(x >= ncol(edhec) - 1, "s", "n"),
        ylab="")
      par(new=TRUE)
      plot(edhec[, x + 1], col="darkgreen", ann=FALSE, xaxt="n", yaxt="n")
      axis(side=4)
  }
))
```

[image]